# After Nuget Enable System Restore I get FileNotFoundException on System.Web.WebPages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I have a web app that I'm managing using TFS.  I have published the app to both a QA and PROD server with no problems.

However, I recently had an issue when trying to load the project on a new machine from TFS because it was missing all the NuGet packages.  I went online and read about the Package Restore feature in 2010.  I enabled that on the project and checked the project in and that fixed my issues.

However, now, whenever I publish to my QA and PROD servers, the site loads and I can hit simple "Index" type pages but anytime I try to load an edit type page (page with a form on it), I get an error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could no load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ...
```

It doesn't appear that anything has changed in my Web.config file.

What happened?  What do I need to do to get my sites back up and running?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phil Haack, I found [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) and it solved my issues.  Basically had to check the box to deploy MVC assemblies.